# 'wb' vs 'w' in Unix for Python

Tags: python-2.7, file, unix

Many posts that considered there's no difference between `wb` and `w` in Unix environments, e.g. [Python file IO 'w' vs 'wb' [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750660/python-file-io-w-vs-wb). But mine works the opposite.

The environment is Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7.13. Executing the following code

```
from __future__ import print_function

log = open("output.txt", "w")
print('{:02d} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(
                queryID,
                "Q0",
                match[0], # filename
                rank,
                match[1], # score
                config.MY_NAME
            ), file = log)
```

Got error:

```
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```

Then I tried to replace with `wb`, problem solved, no more error

```
log = open("output.txt", "wb")
```

Could anyone help explain what's going on here?

Comment: Show your `__future__` imports